# Can not load site

Tags: twig, cakephp-3.0

I'm using `CakePHP3` with `TwigView`. However, I can not load any page on my application. I get the following error at the `src/View/TwigView.php` file. What am I doing wrong?

> Call to a member function loadTemplate() on null

The routing configuration:

```
Router::scope('/', function (RouteBuilder $routes) {
    $routes->connect(
      '/',
      ['controller' => 'Man', 'action' => 'login']
    );
    $routes->connect(
      '/man/*',
      ['controller' => 'Man', 'action' => 'login']
    );
    $routes->fallbacks(DashedRoute::class);
});
```

TwigView Setting

```
// file: src/View/AppView.php
namespace App\View;
use WyriHaximus\TwigView\View\TwigView;

class AppView extends TwigView
{
    public function initialize()
    {
    }
}

// file Application.php
class Application extends BaseApplication
{
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function bootstrap()
    {
        $this->addPlugin('WyriHaximus/TwigView');
        ....
    }
}
```

Layout file

```
// file: Template/Layout/default.tpl
```

Controller

```
class AppController extends Controller
{
    public function initialize()
    {
        parent::initialize();
        $this->viewBuilder()->setLayout("default");
    }
}
```

Comment: Remember to invoke the parent when you override methods, the twig view's `initialize()` method is required to be invoked in order for things to work properly.

Comment: @ndm Oh, that's correct. That is lagging knowledge. Thank you for your help 
I added `parent::initialize();` at the following function

`class AppView extends TwigView
{
    public function initialize()
    {
       parent::initialize();
       $this->_ext = '.tpl';
    }
}`